# HTC Desire (Android 2.2) connects then disconnects to wifi

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, connection-issues, wifi-hotspot

I have a wifi router I want to connect to. It's a TP-Link (Model No. TL-WA901N / TL-WA901ND 2.0). I have enabled WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK on the router, (the default), when I try and connect my HTC Desire to it (Android 2.2), it connects once I enter the password, but never successfully obtains an IP address.

It then it disconnects within a few seconds, it will repeat this 8 times, gives up and then tries the next available network and successfully holds that connection. I do know that the device is connecting initially because I am watching the router's console for connections, and the MAC address that connects matches the my phone.

I am using my router in the default "Access Point" mode, and the default gateway is 192.168.1.254.

Comment: Do you have an access control list set up on your router? if so, remember to add the phone's MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes helps to add the MAC-address of an unconnectable device to the list of allowable MAC-addresses even though all MAC-addresses are allowed by default.

Comment: Thanks... I have found the resetting the router seems to correct the issue.